Python I need more than 1 category in my data request
I am making a lunch module, and I am using data from our vendors website. They use "tag" instead of category. I already took care of that in my code, so that it will go from tag to category id.
I used cURL(bash) to python, that all went fine.
The problem lies in the following: The vendor has four categories of take away, but in the params in I only figured out how to name ONE after the ' "tag"= '. I ofcourse need all four.
I am such a beginner at python and coding in general. I can decypher what other people code, but I am not confident in my own abilities. I already spent alot of time with this issue.
Here is a bit of the code. If I type in one of the other category names where tag is, it will upload that category to my module, so that all works fine, the rest of the code all works. Thanks in advance :)
import requests

headers = {
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Accept-Language': 'nl-NL,nl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'DNT': '1',
    'Referer': 'https://webshop.mywebsiteblahblahblah.nl/',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'script',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'no-cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'cross-site',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Google Chrome";v="131", "Chromium";v="131", "Not_A Brand";v="24"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
}

params = {
    'callback': 'jQuery111200009674179924930026_1732557740249',
    'webshop': '9e04489556c3b92ff80935282b6fda4963fb6a66',
    'session': '3hdilpramoi47rkjrq562q8fc7',
    'tag': 'Broodjes_frisdrank',
    'product': '',
    '_': '1732557740250',
}

response = requests.get('https://webshop.myfak.online/1.4//catalog.php', params=params, headers=headers)

Please help :)
I tried to simply put all the categories down, but I suspect that was a noob-move lol.
'tag'= 'Broodjes_Frisdrank', 'Maaltijdsalades', 'Hartig', 'Soep to go,

Make tag into a list instead of a single string:
'tag': ['Broodjes_frisdrank', 'Maaltijdsalades', 'Hartig'],

